# Can anyone help me understand what is wrong on this code

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is a very stupid exercise

> Given an array of n integers removes the first max element and last min element from that array.

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong? This is the first time I write in VB.

```vb
Imports System

Public Module Program
    Public Sub Main(args() As string)
        Dim numbers = New Integer() {1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 4, 9, 63, 2, 7, 0, 5, 4, 2}
        
    Console.WriteLine("Initial Array {0}" + target)
    
    Dim targetSize As Integer = numbers.Length - 2
    Dim target(targetSize) As Integer
    
    Dim max = numbers(0)
    Dim maxIndex = 0
    
    Dim min = numbers(0)
    Dim minIndex = 0
    
    For index = 0 To numbers.Length
      If max < numbers(index) Then 
        maxIndex = index
        Stop
      End If
    Exit For
    
    For index = 0 To numbers.Length
      If min > numbers(index) Then 
          minIndex = index
      End If
    Exit For
    
    Dim targetIndex As Integer = 0
    
    For index = 0 To numbers.Length
      If (index <> minIndex Or index <> maxIndex) Then
        target(targetIndex) = numbers(index)
        targetIndex = targetIndex + 1
      End If
    Exit For
    Console.WriteLine("Target Array {0}" + target)
    End Sub
End Module
```

And This is the Output.

```
Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943 (Mono 4.0.1 - tarball)
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved.

/runtime/vb/3yn8kpgq9_3ynmpk553/HelloWorld.vb (40,9) : error VBNC30084: CHANGEME
/runtime/vb/3yn8kpgq9_3ynmpk553/HelloWorld.vb (40,9) : error VBNC30084: CHANGEME
/runtime/vb/3yn8kpgq9_3ynmpk553/HelloWorld.vb (40,9) : error VBNC30084: CHANGEME
There were 3 errors and 0 warnings.
Compilation took 00:00:00.4196520

Error: Command failed: timeout 7 vbnc HelloWorld.vb
```

[Online Editor](https://onecompiler.com/vb/3ynmp7shn)

Comment: What variable is `target`?

Comment: Code inside a For statement needs to be delimited by the Next keyword See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement

Comment: What means "first max and last min"? I would understand this if you first determine the max- and min-value of all integers and then you find the first and last with these values(in case of duplicates).

Comment: Also the _min_ and _max_ variables never change. So when you compare values to discover the minimum and maximum index you will never use the new max and min value discovered. The code ends with the bad indexes to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, for example:

- `target` is not declared
- the for-loops have no `Next`
- The `Stop` should be an `Exit For`
- the logic is broken, you want the min- and max-values but you don't check all
- arrays are fixed sized, you cannot remove items, use a `List(Of T)`

You can simplify all to:

```
Dim numbers As Int32() = {1, 2, 4, 8, 5, 4, 9, 63, 2, 7, 0, 5, 4, 2}
Dim min As Int32 = numbers.Min()
Dim max As Int32 = numbers.Max()
Dim numberList As List(Of Int32) = numbers.ToList()
Dim indexOfFirstMax As Int32 = numberList.IndexOf(max)
numberList.RemoveAt(indexOfFirstMax)
Dim indexOfLastMin As Int32 = numberList.LastIndexOf(min)
numberList.RemoveAt(indexOfLastMin)
numbers = numberList.ToArray()
```